# C# Wpf , MediaElement

Tags: c#

Всем привет, помогите с вопросом, есть MediaElement, в нем если ставлю полный путь, то Gif отображается , ставлю относительный путь, Gif не отображается, смотрел похожие вопросы, но не помогло, у меня сейчас вот так

```
<MediaElement VerticalAlignment="Top"  x:Name="gif" UnloadedBehavior="Manual" LoadedBehavior="Play" Stretch="Fill" Source="..\Images\LoadingProgrammm4.gif"
  MediaEnded="gif_MediaEnded"/
```

[image]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код следует вставлять текстом.

Comment: Файлу этому build action - Resource поставьте

Comment: @aepot не помогло, грузится также е просто форма, без гифки

Comment: `Source="Images/LoadingProgrammm4.gif"`

Comment: @aepot сработало, спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для файла LoadingProgrammm4.gif выставьте **Build Action** в значение **Resource**.

Путь в XAML будет выглядеть так:

```xml
<MediaElement ... Source="Images/LoadingProgrammm4.gif" />
```